# Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be differenciable and $[\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)]\cdot (y-x)\ge 0$. Is $f$ a convex fuucntion?

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be differenciable and $[\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)]\cdot (y-x)\ge 0\ \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Is $f$ a convex function?

Since $f$ is differentiable then convexity is equivalent to the condition $$f(y)\ge f(x)+\nabla f(x)\cdot (y-x)\ \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n\ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$ So If there is a function whose derivative satisfy $$[\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)]\cdot (y-x)\ge 0\ \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n\ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$ but $(1)$ is not true then the statement is false.

I know that $$f(y)\ge f(x)+\nabla f(x)\cdot (y-x)\ \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n\Rightarrow [\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)]\cdot (y-x)\ge 0\ \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n,$$ but I can't prove the conversely or find a counterexample.

Comment: cf. [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483590/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the solution was very easy:

Since $[\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)]\cdot (y-x)\ge 0$, then,$$\nabla f(y)\cdot (y-x)\ge\nabla f(x)\cdot (y-x)=\nabla f(x+z)\cdot z\ge\nabla f(x)\cdot z,\ z=y-x.$$
Now, since $f$ is differentiable, then exist $c\in(0,1)$ such that
$$f(x+z)=f(x)+\nabla f(x+cz)\cdot z=f(x)+\frac{1}{c}\nabla f(x+cz)\cdot cz$$
Now using $y=x+cz$ we have that $$f(x+cz)\cdot cz\ge f(x)\cdot cz$$
Then
$$f(x+z)=f(x)+\frac{1}{c}\nabla f(x+cz)\cdot cz\ge f(x)+\frac{1}{c}\nabla f(x)\cdot cz=f(x)+\nabla f(x)\cdot z$$
Then if $w=x+z$, we have that
$$f(w)\ge f(x)+\nabla f(x)\cdot (w-x)$$
So $f$ is convex.